# How to match line feed via perl that's not matched via normal code?

Tags: regex, windows, perl, encoding, character-encoding

I've **[Sample.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wRqgqQ3PVKTk1vSWF2SXFaZFU/view?usp=sharing)** file. I use **changes.pl** and **cmd command** to apply find and replace on *Sample.txt*. I'm looking for removing *line 1* and *line 2*. I've tried using each of **perl lines** in *changes.pl* but I get **[Result.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wRqgqQ3PVKZkdiRWthbDFFcmc/view?usp=sharing)** for all.

**Sample.txt**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

**changes.pl**

```
BEGIN {
    @ARGV = map glob("\"$_\""), @ARGV;
}

s/a/b/g;
```

**cmd command**

```
perl -i.bak -p changes.pl My/Files/Directory/Sample.txt
```

**perl lines**

```
s/line 1\nline 2//g; #perl line 1
s/line 1\n\rline 2//g; #perl line 2
s/line 1\r?\n?\r?line 2//g; #perl line 3
s/line 1\s*line 2//g; #perl line 4
s/line 1.*line 2//su; #perl line 5
s/line 1[\s\S]line 2//g; #perl line 6
```

**Result.txt**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

**Notes**

- I'm using Perl on Windows.
- When I open *Sample.txt* with *Notepad*, I find that *line feeds* aren't shown ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lskUp.png)), while when I open *Result.txt* I find that they are shown ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgiXH.png)). While when I open any of both with *UltraEdit*, I find that *line feeds* are shown ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VgM4.png)). So, I think the problem is related some how to the text encoding. Also, it's advised to download *Sample.txt* and *Result.txt* to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: The `sample.txt` has `LF` (or `\n`) characters for new-lines. Since notepad only considers `CRLF` (or `\r\n`) to be new-line markers, it doesn't display them. As for the substitution pattern, use `ignorecase` modifier.

Comment: MS DOS/Windows text files have usually \r\n (carriage return + line-feed) as line termination and Notepad supports only text files with CRLF as line termination. UNIX text files have only \n as line termination. \n\r is invalid for most OS. UltraEdit detects line termination type and displays it in status bar at bottom of main window for active file. See Wikipedia article about [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the file a line at a time, but you want to perform matches that span lines. Add `-0777` to work on the whole file at a time.

Comment: how to add `0777` and add to what?

Comment: `perl` command-line option `-0777`, as an optional argument to `perl`.